# Error when applying multiple filters in Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on

Tags: google-sheets, analytics, add-on

I am trying to apply 2 filters with [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Addon](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). I want to find the organic session in the specific `pagePath`. I used semicolon between the 2 filters
`="ga:pagePath"&Report!$P9&Report!$G9;ga:medium==organic`.

[image: See image.]

But after entering, I got `Formula parse error.` return. I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `,` instead of `;` as seen in this [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries#search-engines). Also, from this [documentation](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/01/20/google-sheets-segments-and-filters/), to add more than one filter, you need to first think about how you want to filter the data. It's either be an `and(;)` or an `or(,)`.

Comment: I want to see the how many organic sessions visit exact match homepage (ga:pagePath==/) so Is that more appropriate to use and(;) here?